# Microsoft.Graph send mail with attachment

Tags: c#, microsoft-graph-api

```
using Microsoft.Graph
IMessageAttachmentsCollectionPage Message.Attachments
```

I can not seem to get this to take any "ContentBytes" which is in the FileAttachment.ContentBytes.

My sample is from Microsoft https://github.com/microsoftgraph/aspnet-snippets-sample.

```
// Create the message.
Message email = new Message
{
    Body = new ItemBody
    {
        Content = Resource.Prop_Body + guid,
        ContentType = BodyType.Text,
    },
    Subject = Resource.Prop_Subject + guid.Substring(0, 8),
    ToRecipients = recipients,
    HasAttachments = true,
    Attachments = new[]
        {
            new FileAttachment
            {
                ODataType = "#microsoft.graph.fileAttachment",
                ContentBytes = contentBytes,
                ContentType = contentType,
                ContentId = "testing",
                Name = "tesing.png"
            }
        }
};
```

Comment: Want to make clear or clear to me that Assembly Microsoft.Graph, Version=1.2.0.0 sets the JSON property for Attachments. So, if you use it,  you can't send Attachments using it. :) if I said that correctly because the Microsoft.graph.FileAttachment cannot convert to Microsoft.Graph.IMessageAttachmentsCollectionPage.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Using the sample above from GitHub this is resolved, see below:

```
// Create the message with attachment.
byte[] contentBytes = System.IO.File.ReadAllBytes(@"C:\test\test.png");
string contentType = "image/png";
MessageAttachmentsCollectionPage attachments = new MessageAttachmentsCollectionPage();
attachments.Add(new FileAttachment
{
    ODataType = "#microsoft.graph.fileAttachment",
    ContentBytes = contentBytes,
    ContentType = contentType,
    ContentId = "testing",
    Name = "testing.png"
});
Message email = new Message
{
    Body = new ItemBody
    {
        Content = Resource.Prop_Body + guid,
        ContentType = BodyType.Text,
    },
    Subject = Resource.Prop_Subject + guid.Substring(0, 8),
    ToRecipients = recipients,
    Attachments = attachments
};

// Send the message.
await graphClient.Me.SendMail(email, true).Request().PostAsync();
```

Comment: NOTE: 4MB Limit using this method: https://graph.microsoft.io/en-us/docs/api-reference/v1.0/api/message_post_attachments
Since there is currently a limit of 4MB on the total size of each REST request, this limits the size of the attachment you can add to under 4MB.

Answer (score 4):

I'm not quite sure what exactly is going here without seeing a trace of what is being set in the request, an error message, or a http status code. I do know that you can't set the HasAttachments property, that property is only set by the service. Oh, the issue here is that you're setting the Message.Attachments property as a *new[]* instead of a *new MessageAttachmentsCollectionPage*. With that said, I just ran the following code and it worked as expected so we know the service will work for this scenario.

```
        var message = await createEmail("Sent from the MailSendMailWithAttachment test.");

        var attachment = new FileAttachment();
        attachment.ODataType = "#microsoft.graph.fileAttachment";
        attachment.Name = "MyFileAttachment.txt";
        attachment.ContentBytes = Microsoft.Graph.Test.Properties.Resources.textfile;

        message.Attachments = new MessageAttachmentsCollectionPage();
        message.Attachments.Add(attachment);

        await graphClient.Me.SendMail(message, true).Request().PostAsync();
```

I hope this helps and saves you time.

**Update:** This is using Microsoft.Graph.

Comment: I using Microsoft.graph and it has Attachments

Comment: I'm using Microsoft.Graph and it has         [JsonProperty(NullValueHandling = NullValueHandling.Ignore, PropertyName = "attachments", Required = Required.Default)]
        public IMessageAttachmentsCollectionPage Attachments so I do not see how I can use your attachment.ODataType... Tim:

Comment: I do not see how your solution is working due that I don't know if your using Microsoft.Graph or using Newtonsoft.Json - I'm using ONLY Microsoft.Graph and it traps you with cannot Implicily convert Microsoft.graph.FileAttachment to Microsoft.graph.IMessageAttachmentsCollectionPage

Comment: Can you please mark your answer as not complete because it is not using Assembly Microsoft.Graph - it must be "using Newtonsoft.Json Assembly. I just want to try and get this answered and yours is stating that it worked but it did not. Many thanks, Tim:

Comment: The answer I provided is using the Microsoft.Graph client library. I didn't show how the ```message``` was created