# Graph API SendMail with Attachment using REST example in c#

Tags: microsoft-graph-api

[Graph API Send Email](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/api-reference/v1.0/api/user_sendmail) document states that I can include a file attachment in the same sendMail action call. Would someone be able to provide an example code of how this can be achieved using me/sendmail with attachment from the file generated which content is stored in the memorystream?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

One option is to use the [Microsoft Graph .NET SDK](https://github.com/microsoftgraph/msgraph-sdk-dotnet) and I found this sample code in another [Stack Overflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42394414/2517012).

```cs
// Create the message with attachment.
byte[] contentBytes = System.IO.File.ReadAllBytes(@"C:\test\test.png");
string contentType = "image/png";
MessageAttachmentsCollectionPage attachments = new MessageAttachmentsCollectionPage();
attachments.Add(new FileAttachment
{
    ODataType = "#microsoft.graph.fileAttachment",
    ContentBytes = contentBytes,
    ContentType = contentType,
    ContentId = "testing",
    Name = "testing.png"
});
Message email = new Message
{
    Body = new ItemBody
    {
        Content = Resource.Prop_Body + guid,
        ContentType = BodyType.Text,
    },
    Subject = Resource.Prop_Subject + guid.Substring(0, 8),
    ToRecipients = recipients,
    Attachments = attachments
};

// Send the message.
await graphClient.Me.SendMail(email, true).Request().PostAsync();
```

Comment: I was asking for the REST sample, not SDK