# Microsoft.Graph send mail with image path fetching from Azure Keyvault

Tags: c#, .net, outlook, microsoft-graph-api

In the previous code implementation the mail functionality was implemented using SmtpClient("smtp.office365.com"). and the image path was retrieved from Keyvault and implemented as below.

```
public void MailSend(){   
SmtpClient SmtpServer = new SmtpClient("smtp.office365.com");
MailMessage message = new MailMessage();
message.Attachments.Add(new Attachment(AzureVaultIntegrationLayer.RetrieveKeysFromKeyVault("Pic_Path")));
SmtpServer.Send(message);
}
```

Now in the current MS Graph API (mail.send API ) what would be the approach/implementation to pass this image from KeyVault in the message body.

Comment: (1) Register an application in AAD portal (2) configure the app to use a right Azure AD flow say, [delegated permissions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/auth-v2-user) or [application permissions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/auth-v2-service) (3) Get the token with necessary roles/permissions to access the protected resources (say, MS Graph) (4) Now you can call the Graph endpoint and [make API call](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/outlook-create-send-messages) to create email messages, create the body, add the azurevault image part of it and send it over.

Comment: Thanks @Dev but I want to pass the above attachment from the KeyVault in the below code as mentioned on the [link](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/graph-explorer) MS Graph Explorer Site.`var message = new Message`
`{`
 `Subject = "Meet for lunch?",`
 `Body = new ItemBody`
 `{`
  `ContentType = BodyType.Text,`
  `Content = "The new cafeteria is open."`
 `},`
 `ToRecipients = new List<Recipient>()`
 `{`
  `new Recipient`
  `{`
   `EmailAddress = new EmailAddress`
   `{`
    `Address = "garthf@contoso.com"`
   `}`
  `}`
 `}`
`};`

Comment: you may want to try the code sample provided at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42374501/microsoft-graph-send-mail-with-attachment/42394414#42394414 to send email with attachments (replace the physical path with your keyvault info), @Network_127!!

Comment: Does it helped?